# How to get the source of a property by subscribing to an event stream?

Tags: java, javafx, reactfx

if I have a JavaFX property and I create an event stream from this property:

```
EventStreams.nonNullValuesOf(node.boundsInParentProperty())
```

Is there a possibility to set the source (in this case the "node") at creation time or to get this object later in a subscription?

For example:

```
EventStream<...> stream = EventStreams.nonNullValuesOf(node.boundsInParentProperty());

...
stream.subscribe((node, bounds) -> ...);
```

or at creation time:

```
EventStream<...> stream = EventStreams.valueAndSource(node.boundsInParentProperty(), node);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I got what I want with:

```
EventStreams.nonNullValuesOf(node.boundsInParentProperty()).map(bounds -> ...)
```

My problem was that I have a list with N node objects which are reachable at iteration time. Solved my problem like:

```
EventStream<Tuple2<Node, Bounds>> eventStream = nodes.stream().
map(node -> EventStreams.nonNullValuesOf(node.boundsInParentProperty()).map(bounds -> Tuples.t(node, bounds))).
reduce((es, esAccu) -> EventStreams.merge(es, esAccu)).
orElse(EventStreams.never());
```